# C++ Iterating over vector of class pointers and using base function

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector

I am trying to loop over a vector of pointers to my class, let's call it `MyClass`, and call a method within `MyClass` for each element in the vector, let's call it `MyMethod`. That is:

```
std::vector<MyClass*> ClassOne;
for(auto it: ClassOne){
    ClassOne[it].MyMethod();
}
```

But evidently this does not work. Could someone please explain how to fix this but also what my code here is actually doing (as opposed to what I thought it should be doing).

Thanks!

Comment: What if the vector had objects instead of pointers?  What would the loop look like?  If you know the answer to that question, then that practically answers the question you've posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use,

```
for(auto it: ClassOne)
{
   // ...
}
```

`it` is a `MyClass*`, not an an `int`. Hence you need to change the call to `MyMethod` to

```
it->MyMethod();
```

The `for` loop needs to be:

```
for(auto it: ClassOne)
{
   it->MyMethod();
}
```

Comment: Ahhhhh OK, this makes a lot of sense thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are using range-based for loop, hence you should be using

```
for(auto it: ClassOne){
    it -> MyMethod();
}
```

`it` is not an index. It's a copy of the element (the element of the vector which is a pointer) itself. It can be the element itself by using

```
for(auto & it: ClassOne){
    it -> MyMethod();
}
```

instead. but this is not optimal here.

Please, note that it's not recommended to use plain pointers. use [smart ones](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) instead.

Comment: Unless `it` is a reference (which it isn't, unless you do `for (auto &it : ClassOne)`), then `it` is a pointer that has a copied value of an element, not the element itself.